# Rerender based on picklist field

Tags: visualforce, rerender, actionsupport

I'm trying to display some text if a particular value is chosen on a picklist.  I thought that I could do this by using reRender however I am wondering if I also need a method in my controller?  I've been researching, but have not identified why the message is not rendering.  Below is the section of the page:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="FlagType">
     <apex:inputField id="redflagtype" value="{!Loan_Memo__c.RedFlagType__c}" required="true">
        <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" rerender="Reminder" />
     </apex:inputField>       
     <apex:outputpanel id="Reminder" > 
          <apex:outputText value="You have selected Direct Pay, Please attach a copy of the check." rendered="{!Loan_Memo__c.RedFlagType__c == 'Direct Pay'}" /> 
      </apex:outputpanel>   
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: You can't rerender an element wich have a rendered condition. Try to add an outputpanel as parent of your ouputText and rerender this panel.

Comment: So nest like this? <apex:outputpanel id="Reminder" > 
                            <apex:outputpanel >
                            <apex:outputText value="You have selected Direct Pay, Please attach a copy of the check." rendered="{!Loan_Memo__c.RedFlagType__c == 'Direct Pay'}" />
                            </apex:outputpanel>    
                     </apex:outputpanel>     I tried that but am still not seeing the text display?

Comment: I think it's already structured correctly in that regard. It seems to me like perhaps your `actionSupport` may not be firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize that required fields would prevent rerender from firing. Enclosing the section in actionRegion tags solved the issue:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="FlagType">
   <apex:actionRegion>
        <apex:inputField id="redflagtype" value="{!Loan_Memo__c.RedFlagType__c}" required="true">
           <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" rerender="Reminder"  />
        </apex:inputField>       
        <apex:outputpanel id="Reminder" > 
                     <apex:outputText value="You have selected Direct Pay, Please attach a copy of the check." rendered="{!Loan_Memo__c.RedFlagType__c == 'Direct Pay'}" /> 
        </apex:outputpanel>  
    </apex:actionRegion>       
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

References:

- [Rerender not firing if required fields are empty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60401/rerender-not-firing-if-required-fields-are-empty)
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionRegion.htm

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to modify your code, putting an `action` at `actionSupport` and returning back the value from the controller.

So from the action it will call `dummyActions()` method of the controller, then assign the selected value in `redFlagType` variable.

Finally, based on `redFlagType == 'Direct Pay'` displaying the `outputText`

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="FlagType">
     <apex:inputField id="redflagtype" value="{!Loan_Memo__c.RedFlagType__c}" required="true">
        <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" rerender="Reminder" action="{!dummyActions}"/>
     </apex:inputField>       
     <apex:outputpanel id="Reminder" > 
          <apex:outputText value="You have selected Direct Pay, Please attach a copy of the check." 
          rendered="{!redFlagType == 'Direct Pay'}" /> 
      </apex:outputpanel>   
</apex:pageBlockSection>

public String redFlagType {get; set;}
public PageReference dummyActions(){
    //do your stuff
    redFlagType = Loan_Memo__c.RedFlagType__c;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: on this line: redFlagType = Loan_Memo__c.RedFlagType__c I assume that I would actually use the variable that I've set? public Loan_Memo__c  myMemo {get;set;} so it would read: redFlagType = mymemo.RedFlagType__c?  I've tried that but I'm still not seeing the text displayed.  Do I need to do something else to pass the value back to the controller?